# Using Ninject with Udi Dahan's Domain Events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, domain-events

I'm using Ninject in an MVC project and am trying to implement Domain Events following Udi Dahan's pattern http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/

In the extract below, the "Container" is used to resolve all the event-handlers for the particular type of event that has been raised.

My question (& apologies if I am missing something basic) is how to do this with Ninject?  In other words:

1. How does the "Container" get set in this static class?
2. Once I have a Container (Kernel?) what would be the Ninject syntax to resolve all the event handlers (which I'm assuming I would have to register before-hand in a Service Module)?

I keep reading in posts that only constructor injection should be used and everything recursively get resolved from that, and that accessing the Ninject Kernel is a no-no.  So any advice on how to do this will be much appreciated.

**Extract from the article**

```
public static class DomainEvents
{ 
  [ThreadStatic] //so that each thread has its own callbacks
  private static List<Delegate> actions; 

  public static IContainer Container { get; set; } //as before

  //Registers a callback for the given domain event
  public static void Register<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : IDomainEvent
  {
     if (actions == null)
        actions = new List<Delegate>();

     actions.Add(callback);
 }

 //Clears callbacks passed to Register on the current thread
 public static void ClearCallbacks ()
 {
     actions = null;
 }

 //Raises the given domain event
 public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
 {
    if (Container != null)
       foreach(var handler in Container.ResolveAll<Handles<T>>())
          handler.Handle(args);

    if (actions != null)
        foreach (var action in actions)
            if (action is Action<T>)
                ((Action<T>)action)(args);
 }
}
```

Comment: There is a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444646/integrating-di-container-within-domain-layer-domain-events?rq=1 but the answer doesn't give a code example, so I'm still not clear how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does the "Container" get set in this static class?

You will have to set it during application startup:

```
DomainEvents.Container = kernel;
```

> what would be the Ninject syntax to resolve all the event handlers:

You can do it like this, for instance:

```
Container.Get<IEnumerable<Handles<T>>>())
```

Udi's static `DomainEvents` class is an implementation of the *Ambient Context* anti-pattern (see [DI PP&P](https://manning.com/seemann2) chapter [5.3](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition/chapter-5/section-5-3)). In this case I would rather use dependency injection to inject an `IDomainEvents` abstraction into code that needs it, instead of letting code depend on a static instance.

The problem however is that your domain objects will need a dependency on the `IDomainEvents` and constructor injection is (probably) not possible. The trick is to use method injection in that case.

In other words, use constructor injection to inject the `IDomainEvents` into command handlers or services (or what ever you call your business logic that uses the methods on your domain objects) and pass that dependency into the domain object when calling a method that needs it (method injection).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer - gave me some useful pointers.  I'm using the NuGet implementation of Ninject for MVC, so will set DomainEvents.Controller in the App_Start/NinjectWebCommon class somewhere.  I think I'll have to stick with the static DomainEvents class as injecting IDomainEvents into all my Entity Framework code-first models isn't possible at this stage.  A static DomainEvents is still unit-testable (as described in Udi's original article), so I can live with that.  Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of injecting IDomainEvents via a method, you can also let your domain object implement something like IRecordEvents, and have the upper layer forward the recorded events to a dispatcher.