# Breaking the "ubiquitous language" by having an IoC in Domain Model?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ioc-container, onion-architecture, domain-events

My question is about [Udi's solution](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) to domain events, particularly the class `DomainEvents` (see code below)

An excerpt from Udi's code. It lives domain model as a static class.

```
public static class DomainEvents
{ 
   [ThreadStatic] //so that each thread has its own callbacks
   private static List<Delegate> actions;

   public static IContainer Container { get; set; } //as before

   //Registers a callback for the given domain event
   public static void Register<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : IDomainEvent
   {
      if (actions == null)
         actions = new List<Delegate>();

      actions.Add(callback);
  }

  //Clears callbacks passed to Register on the current thread
  public static void ClearCallbacks ()
  { 
      actions = null;
  }

  //Raises the given domain event
  public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
  {
     if (Container != null)
        foreach(var handler in Container.ResolveAll<Handles<T>>())
           handler.Handle(args);

     if (actions != null)
         foreach (var action in actions)
             if (action is Action<T>)
                 ((Action<T>)action)(args);
  }
}
```

From the code above, the static member `IContainer` creates an ioc-container-dependency in the domain model. Though I am not really sure if Udi's `IContainer` is an interface or an actual IoC container.

I don't see anything like this in his sample:

```
public interface IContainer
{
    IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>();
}
```

My 1st question is: **What is this `IContainer` in the `DomainEvents` class?** If it is truly an IoC container then doesn't it break the rule of *"not having an infrastructure in the domain"*? (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Isn't the idea of DDD is about separating the infrastructure from the domain?

My 2nd question is: **Does `DomainEvents` itself breaks the rule *"ubiquitous language of DDD"***? Because it's implementation does not pertain to any domain.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015486/using-ninject-with-udi-dahans-domain-events/13026232#13026232

Answer (score 3):

I agree, the domain must not know about infrastructure and, to a certain degree, Udi's solution provides that abstraction. Personally, I prefer the solution hinted at by Mark Seemann in the article's comments: inject the event aggregator via an interface. This way, events hold there place as first class domain model citizens, but via the loosest of coupling.

Comment: But isn't the `DomainEvents` class considered an infrastructure? Especially that it has IContainer. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I would argue that the DomainEvents class conceals its dependencies on infrastructure-type components. I don't need to know that it's using Castle Windsor to raise a domain event. The coupling could be looser if the model classes only depended on an interface for raising events. However, I think both approaches are valid.